# how to run cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-bluetooth on cordova

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, google-chrome-app

i have a cordova app with plugins **cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-bluetooth** and **cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-common**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-bluetooth
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-common
```

I'm trying to read result of  **chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState()**

```
app.scan = function () {
    console.log("app.scan()");
    var res = chrome.bluetooth.getAdapterState( function(  adapterInfo )  {
            console.log("callback");
            console.log("adapterInfo");
        }
    );
};
```

in index.html :

```
<button on-click="app.scan()" >scan</button>
```

In chrome js console, i can see app.scan() but the callback never shows up.

is this plugin should really work in cordova ? or may be am i missing something?

Comment: Since the content security policy for Chrome Apps, inline JS script is not allowed here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the plugin "cordova-plugin-android-support-v4", it worked for me. It is being discussed in this thread: https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-bluetooth/issues/3#issuecomment-144164329